# URL Path Pattern matching in wiremock

Tags: java, wiremock

How does exactly wiremock matches the URL Path Pattern with encoded URLs? Do I need to save mapping with already encoded URL? Here is what I tried for several hours and can't get it to working.

Mapping in wiremock

```
"request": {
    "urlPathPattern": "/Systems XYZ (ABC)/2016.10/aaa/bbb/api/ccc/customers/.*",
    "method": "GET",
```

I've already tried with different variants with encoded URL e.g. /Systems%20XYZ%20(ABC)/2016.10/aaa/bbb/api/ccc/customers/.*
or even URL encoding the ( and ) in mappings but my request doesn't seems to be matching

What URI I tried to invoke the service against wiremock
/Systems%20XYZ%20(ABC)/2016.10/aaa/bbb/api/ccc/customers/12345

/Systems XYZ (ABC)/2016.10/aaa/bbb/api/ccc/customers/.*
Though, I assume Postman/browser will encode the spaces automatically.

Is there anything I'm missing here? Have tried many combinations but did not seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

When using [WireMock.Net](https://github.com/StefH/WireMock.Net), you should be able to use this example:

```
{
  "Request": {
    "Path": {
      "Matchers": [
        {
          "Name": "RegexMatcher",
          "Pattern": "^/Systems XYZ (ABC)/2016.10/aaa/bbb/api/ccc/customers/.*$"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Response": {
    "BodyAsJson": { "result": "test" },
    "Headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```